# Convert SQL - Linq with SQL IN

Tags: c#, linq

I have this sql query below working fine. I want to convert it `LINQ`

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT PersonId, FamilyName, GivenName, MiddleName, CompleteName
 FROM         dbo.MainTable AS a
 WHERE     (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table1
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId))) OR
                  (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table2
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId))) OR
                  (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table3
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId)))
ORDER BY FamilyName
```

**Code Tried**

```
 var Sigids = (from a in db.Table1 select a.PersonId);
 var RecIds = (from a in db.Table2 select a.PersonId);
 var AppIds = (from a in db.Table3 select a.PersonId);
 var signatories = (from p in db.MainTable
                   where (Sigids.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   && RecIds.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   && AppIds.Contains(p.PersonId))
                   select new { CompleteName = p.CompleteName, p.PersonId });
```

But this results only if a personId is those 3 tables. What I want to achieve here is I want to display all names of Table 1 - 3 from the mainTable.

Comment: What is s1 in `where s1.IsActive == true`?

Comment: Since the where condition in your SQL query is using `OR`, the `&&` in the where condition in your linq code should be changed to `||`.

Comment: @CodingYoshi aw sorry. I remove the join and I forgot to remove it.

Comment: It should work if you make the changes as @ekad has suggested.

Comment: @ekad Thanks a lot. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the where condition in your sql query below

```
 WHERE     (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table1
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId))) OR
                  (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table2
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId))) OR
                  (PersonId IN
                      (SELECT     PersonId
                        FROM          dbo.Table3
                        WHERE      (PersonId = a.PersonId)))
```

The equivalent of `OR` operator in linq is either `|` or `||` instead of `&&`. Your linq code should be changed to below using `|`:

```
 var Sigids = (from a in db.Table1 select a.PersonId);
 var RecIds = (from a in db.Table2 select a.PersonId);
 var AppIds = (from a in db.Table3 select a.PersonId);
 var signatories = (from p in db.MainTable
                   where (Sigids.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   | RecIds.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   | AppIds.Contains(p.PersonId))
                   select new { CompleteName = p.CompleteName, p.PersonId });
```

Or like below using `||`:

```
 var Sigids = (from a in db.Table1 select a.PersonId);
 var RecIds = (from a in db.Table2 select a.PersonId);
 var AppIds = (from a in db.Table3 select a.PersonId);
 var signatories = (from p in db.MainTable
                   where (Sigids.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   || RecIds.Contains(p.PersonId)
                   || AppIds.Contains(p.PersonId))
                   select new { CompleteName = p.CompleteName, p.PersonId });
```